# Tmux Selection in one Pane?

Tags: tmux

I have an issue when selecting in split window it didn't select from one pane as in the GIF

[image]

I select using (Shift + Mouse)
How Can I Solve this issue ?

Comment: I guess `tmux` is not even aware you're selecting. Possibly your terminal emulator does this on its own. What terminal emulator is it?

Comment: I use Terminator